# Passing Multiple Parameters to a Function C++

Tags: c++

My third function wper won't recognize the values of the first and second one. Xcode states that every time I reference wper it will always evaluate to true, as opposed to a percentage. The objective is to take the values  from the first and second function, calculate a percentage in the third, and display it in the main function. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
double wins();
double loses();

double wper();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    wins();

    loses();

    wper();

    cout << "Your team's winning percentage is " << setprecision(2) << fixed << wper << "%"<< endl;
};


double wins(){

    double wins;

    cout << "How many games did your team win this season?" << endl;
    cin >> wins;

    return wins;
};

double loses() {

    double loses;

    cout << "How many games did your team lose this season?" << endl;
    cin >> loses;

    return loses;
};

double wper(double wins, double loses){

    double per = (wins / (wins + loses));

    return per;
};
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaw, physical pains! I'm going to sue you having been blinded by reading this question.

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiled, what are you using? Forward declaration on an overload without a function definition. Also it seems counter intuitive to use a double rather than a float for a percentage that you will probably round anyway.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's an emergency.

Comment: Xcode. In the above form, it hasn't actually compiled. Prior to this, I managed to get everything to compile and print but the percentage always returned 1

Answer (score 1):

Not to be rude, but I take it you're new to C++?

You should be storing function results/return values as variables and then passing them as parameters to `wper(double, double)`

Below is a revised version of your code with some comments:

```
#include <iostream>

// Forward declare functions:
double wins();
double losses();
double wper(double wins, double losses);

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Get input:
    double dWinCount = wins();
    double dLossCount = losses();

    // Calculate win percent:
    double dWinPercent = wper(dWinCount, dLossCount) * 100; // x100 to make it a percent

    // Set the double output to be 2 decimal places fixed:
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setpercision(2);

    cout << "Your team's winning percentage is " << dWinPercent << "%"<< endl;
}


double wins(){

    double wins;

    cout << "How many games did your team win this season?" << endl;
    cin >> wins;

    return wins;
}

double losses() {

    double losses;

    cout << "How many games did your team lose this season?" << endl;
    cin >> losses;

    return losses;
}

double wper(double wins, double losses){
    double per = (wins / (wins + losses));
    return per;
}
```

Also, as stated in the comments on your question and another answer, using `double` is a little bit unnecessary. A `float` would suffice for your needs because you don't need to be highly precise here. A `double` also takes up twice as many bytes in memory (8 bytes) as compared to a `float` (4 bytes) (hence why a double can be more precise than a float). This extra memory consumption is negligible in a program of this size, but being efficient with memory by using proper data types can be very important in larger projects, so it's a good practice to keep your memory footprint small.

Comment: Yes this is my freshmen year and my first time taking a coding class. Also, I need three separate functions in addition to the main (which may help explain why it looks so odd).

Comment: Thanks . That makes a lot more sense

Comment: @ace7, ahh that makes more sense then. I'm surprised they started the freshmen out with C++. Based on my own experience with programming classes, C++ is generally a language that isn't introduced until later on. Regardless, I can remember when I started trying to learn C++ (I was trying to learn it on my own). It can certainly be an intimidating language for newcomers :P

Comment: Honestly everything was pretty straightforward (class average was around A) until we introduced loops last week (now class average is around B). Functions seemed very simple until everyone realized they couldn't pass values from the function back to main.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably lies in your forward declaration of the wper function.

You should have the right forward declaration meaning something like this instead of what you currently have:

```
double wper(double wins, double loses);
```

However I would suggest that you try to clean up your code a little and as suggested in the comments think about using float instead of double for percentages.